# Hyper-V Delete VM J-Interop

Tags: java, hyper-v

I want to modify Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService resource and want to use DestroySystem method of the Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService.. for that purpose i want to get A reference to an instance of the CIM_ComputerSystem that represents the virtual machine instance to be destroyed. But i don't know how to get using j-interop.. Kindly help me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using http://jwbem.sourceforge.net/ you should be able to get a Msvm_ComputerSystem reference

(sample from jwbem doc)

```
import com.hyper9.jwbem.SWbemObjectSet;
import com.hyper9.jwbem.msvm.MsvmComputerSystem;

...

// Define the WQL query that returns all of a Hyper-V's virtual machines.
String wql = "SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE Caption='Virtual Machine'";

// Execute the query.
SWbemObjectSet<MsvmComputerSystem> compSysSet = svc.execQuery(wql, MsvmComputerSystem.class);

// Print the names of the virtual machines.
for (MsvmComputerSystem cs : compSysSet)
{
  System.out.println(cs.getElementName());
}
```